# Pushing 2 combined projects to github together (regular project and test project)

Tags: java, testing, junit

So I have my main project, and another project for testing the main project functionality.
I have pushed my main project to a github repo, but I cant seem to figure out how should I push the test project?
in the Eclipse workspace folder they are 2 seperate projects, so how should I do that?

thanks

Comment: That will be a separate project.

Comment: so you mean I should put it in a different repo entierly?